# combination with duplicate id must be unique in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a table BonusPay with Employee ID,Account Number,Account Types,Bank ID and some other columns.

I need to write query which returns non unique Employee ID in sql

**Duplicate Employee ID+Account Number+Bank ID+Account Types. Combination must be unique.**

I wrote query to find duplicate employee ID

```
(SELECT [Employee ID],COUNT([Employee ID]) 
FROM [BASEP1].[INTERIM - Bonus Pay Election Enrollment] 
GROUP BY [Employee ID] 
HAVING COUNT([Employee ID])>1)
```

please help me how to proceed further

Table 
 **Employee ID  Account Number  Bank ID Number  Account Type
    DC21002 1042044011  121000358   SA
    DC21004 8840215401  271070801   DDA
    DC21005 9942011555  21000089    DDA
    DC21106 0033384728  NULL    DDA
    DC21117 NULL    121000358   SA
    DC21053 0448921114  11000138    NULL
    DC21003 4505120541  121000248   DDA
    DC21007 5981285871  121000358   SA
    DC21095 5400147754  121000358   SA
    DC21095 0035793301  121000358   DDA
    DC21044 0493540121  121000248   SA
    DC21039 NULL    NULL    NULL

Now take duplicate ID's,Combine with other columns.
The resulting looks like

```
select [Employee ID]+[Account Number]+[Bank ID Number]+[Account Type]
from [BASEP1].[INTERIM - Bonus Pay Election Enrollment]
```

DC210021042044011121000358SA
DC210048840215401271070801DDA
DC21005994201155521000089DDA
DC21117NULL121000358SA
Now check this resulting combination is unique or not

Comment: You are there add other fields to the select and group by.

Comment: Can you show us some sample data of your input and expected output?

Comment: BonusPay Table     Employee ID

Answer (score 0):

Put your query identifying the duplicates into a Common Table Expression, then join your duplicate values onto your original table to get your results.

```
;with CTE as
(SELECT [Employee ID],COUNT([Employee ID]) 
FROM [BASEP1].[INTERIM - Bonus Pay Election Enrollment] 
GROUP BY [Employee ID] 
HAVING COUNT([Employee ID])>1)
select distinct employee ID
from [BASEP1].[INTERIM - Bonus Pay Election Enrollment] b
join cte a on a.[employee id] on b.[employee id]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly(correct me if I am wrong) then you want to find the duplicate of combination `Employee ID+Account Number+Bank ID+Account Types` then just do the group by on it. This will do the grouping on the uniq combination of the `Employee ID+Account Number+Bank ID+Account Types`

```
    ;WITH CTE
      (
       SELECT [Employee ID],COUNT([Employee ID]) as duplicatecount
       FROM [BASEP1].[INTERIM - Bonus Pay Election Enrollment] 
       GROUP BY [Employee ID]
       HAVING COUNT([Employee ID])>1
      )
    Select c.EmployeeID,
           t.AccountNumber,
           t.BankID,
           t.AccountType
    FROM
        CTE c Join [BASEP1].[INTERIM - Bonus Pay Election Enrollment] t
         ON c.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Take only duplicate Emp ID's and then concatenate with other columns Account Number,Bank ID,Account Types .that resulting string should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find duplicate rows you could try this one:

```
SELECT
    [Employee ID],
    [Account Number],
    [Bank ID],
    [Account Types],
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    [BASEP1].[INTERIM - Bonus Pay Election Enrollment] 
GROUP BY
    [Employee ID],
    [Account Number],
    [Bank ID],
    [Account Types]
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I get this error :''Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.''

Comment: I hardly use MS SQL. I'm not sure if group by column reference is supported. I just removed the references (group by 1,2,3,4) and added the column names.

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't that statement do the job?:

```
SELECT [Employee ID]
    FROM [BASEP1].[INTERIM - Bonus Pay Election Enrollment] 
    GROUP BY [Employee ID] 
    HAVING COUNT([Employee ID])>1;
```

Comment: Ok nvm. I didn't get you wanted to select multiple col. Just go with it like others mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [Employee ID]
            ,[Account Number]
            ,[Bank ID]
            ,[Account Types]
            order by [Employee ID]    
            ) ROWNUM
    FROM [BASEP1].[INTERIM - Bonus Pay Election Enrollment]
    )
SELECT *
    ,[Employee ID] + [Account Number] + [Bank ID] + [Account Types] + ROWNUM AS [New Employee ID]
FROM CTE
```

Comment: error:''The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.''